# About the construction of the exponential

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

**Context.**

We can construct the exponential function $\exp\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ by solving the following functional equation:

$$\begin{cases} \forall x,y\in \mathbb R,\quad f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\\ f\in C^1(\mathbb R)\\ f(0)=f'(0)=1.\end{cases}$$

**The question.**

If we take a function $f$ such that

$$\begin{cases}\forall x,y\in \mathbb R,\quad f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) \\ f(0)=1.\end{cases}$$

we can see that

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=f(x)f(h)-f(x)=f(x)(f(h)-1).$$

So if we assume $f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$,

$$\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h)=f(x)\iff \lim_{h\to 0} f(h)=1.$$

Then,

$$f\text{ is continuous at $x$} \iff f\text{ is continuous at $0$}.$$

Is this correct?

If so, can we prove such a $f$ is always continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: I think you mean $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ at the two parts in the beginning

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. But there are discontinuous solutions to the functional equation. But if we assume continuity at any point then we can prove that either the function is $0$ identically or is of the form $e^{kx} $.

Comment: In any event, I don't think such a function must be continuous at $0$. I think a counterexample may be constructed the same way as for the Cauchy functional equation: $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$. The point is, the Cauchy functional equation and the one you gave also give information about $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ once you know $f(0)$. There's no way you can find out $f(\sqrt{2})$ for example.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That is what I was wondering. What are they? (because it would answer the question by : *no*).

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks, I will look up a counterexample for Cauchy functional equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. But theree are discontinuous functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow(0,+\infty)$ such that $f(0)=1$ and that $(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}):f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. Just take a discontinuous function $\eta\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}):\eta(x+y)=\eta(x)+\eta(y)$ and define $f(x)=e^{\eta(x)}$.